# Child component failed to load in Angular 9

Tags: angular, router, children

for example works!

```
  { path: 'products/:id', component: ItemComponent, 
    children: [

      { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent } 

  ] }, 

  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },


   http//localhost:4200/products   --->  (ProductsComponent)  works!
   http//localhost:4200/products/1   ---> (ItemComponent) works!
   http//localhost:4200/products/1/gallery --->(GalleryComponent) works!
```

But... in the same file not works!

```
   { path: 'category/:id', component: SinglecategoryComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'sub', component: SubcategoryComponent } 

   ] },

   { path: 'category', component: CategoryComponent },

   http//localhost:4200/category    --->  (CategoryComponent )  works!
   http//localhost:4200/category/1   ---> (SinglecategoryComponent) works!
   http//localhost:4200/products/1/sub  --->(SinglecategoryComponent) ¿? Not works!
```

Alguna idea?

this

```
   http//localhost:4200/products/1/sub
```

should show

```
   SubcategoryComponent
```

but should show

```
  SinglecategoryComponent
```

any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this url http//localhost:4200/products/1/sub incorrect? It should be http//localhost:4200/category/1/sub according to your route config.